# Using own descriptor and feature in Visual Structure From Motion

Tags: opencv, sift, descriptor, feature-descriptor

Hi i'm using program Visual Structure From Motion to recover the structure  of a 3d-place. However, i 've already computed my descriptors and my features; so i want to use them in Visual Structure From Motion.I've read that the file which contains informations about descriptor should has the following pattern:

[Header][Location Data][Descriptor Data][EOF]

[Header] = int[5] = {name, version, npoint, 5, 128};
name = ('S'+ ('I'<<8)+('F'<<16)+('T'<<24));
version = ('V'+('4'<<8)+('.'<<16)+('0'<<24)); or ('V'+('5'<<8)+('.'<<16)+('0'<<24)) if containing color info
npoint = number of features.

[Location Data]  is a npoint x 5 float matrix and each row  is [x, y, color, scale, orientation]. 
Write color by casting the float to unsigned char[4]
scale & orientation are only used for visualization, so you can simply write 0 for them

- Sort features in the order of decreasing importance, since VisualSFM may use only part of those features.
- VisualSFM sorts the features in the order of decreasing scales.

[Descriptor Data] is a npoint x 128 unsigned char matrix. Note the feature descriptors are normalized to 512.

[EOF]  int eof_marker = (0xff+('E'<<8)+('O'<<16)+('F'<<24));

There's someone that write a concrete example of this file? This file should be generated automatically by my application.

Comment: is VisualSFM a openCV method/class?

Comment: Visual Structure From Motion is a program for computer vision application.It's not a method or class of this library.